# EF Code First Entity Base Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

all of the tables in our Oracle (legacy) database has the fields:

```
Created_By
Creation_Date
Updated_By
UpdateDate
```

which are controlled by triggers. I made an abstract `EntityBase` class which contains the the four properties, and that works great. I Do however need to add the four properties to each config file(fluent)(They have different names in the database and in my classes). Can i make a base configuration file for `EntityTypeConfiguration`, which all the other config files can derive from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that is currently supported but there is an item on the backlog for it.